# Traverse 2D Array (Matrix) Diagonally

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112832/traverse-rectangular-matrix-in-diagonal-strips) thread that was extremely helpful in traversing an array diagonally. I'm stuck though on mirroring it. For example:

```
var m = 3;
var n = 4;
var a = new Array();
var b = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  a[i] = new Array(n);
  for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[i][j] = b;
      b++;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < m + n - 1; i++) {
  var z1 = (i < n) ? 0 : i - n + 1;
  var z2 = (i < m) ? 0 : i - m + 1;
  for (var j = i - z2; j >= z1; j--) {
    console.log(a[j][i - j]);
  }
}
```

Console reads `[[0],[4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3],[10,7],[11]]`

I'd like it to read `[[8],[4,9],[0,5,10],[1,6,11],[2,7],[3]]`

Been stumped for awhile, it's like a rubik's cube >_<

Comment: no, self taught programmer ... not in school anymore. Maybe I should go back :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I found the whole z1, z2 logic a bit unreadable, so I did it a bit differently:

```
var m = 3;
var n = 4;
var a = new Array();
var b = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  a[i] = new Array(n);
  for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[i][j] = b;
      b++;
  }
}

var out = new Array();
for (var i = 1 - m; i < n; i++) {
    var group = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if ((i + j) >= 0 && (i + j) < n) {
            group.push(a[j][i + j]);
        }
    }
    out.push(group);
}
console.log(out);
```

Prints `[[8], [4, 9], [0, 5, 10], [1, 6, 11], [2, 7], [3]]` to the console.

#### How it works

Your matrix construction gives you a rectangle like this (where your `a` array is the set of rows):

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
```

Which means the diagonals are over this grid:

```
 #  #  0  1  2  3
    #  4  5  6  7  #
       8  9 10 11  #  #
```

Now we're just looping over a skewed rectangle, that would look like this normalised:

```
 #  #  0  1  2  3
 #  4  5  6  7  #
 8  9 10 11  #  #
```

Now you'll notice that for each row you add, you end up with an extra column (starting with a `#`) and that the first column is now skewed by this amount (if you imagine holding the first row in place & sliding the rows below to the left). So for our outer `for` loop (over the columns), the first column is effectively the old first column, `0`, minus the number of rows `m`, plus `1`, which gives `0 - m + 1` or `1 - m`. The last column effectively stays in place, so we're still looping to `n`. Then its just a matter of taking each column & looping over each of the `m` rows (inner `for` loop).

Of course this leaves you with a bunch of `undefined`s (the `#`s in the grid above), but we can skip over them with a simple `if` to make sure our `i` & `j` are within the `m` & `n` bounds.

Probably slightly less efficient than the `z1`/`z1` version since we're now looping over the redundant `#` cells rather than pre-calculating them, but it shouldn't make any real world difference & I think the code ends up much more readable.

Comment: I agree, this explains the logic behind it so well. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
Initialize the 2-D array.
*/      
String array2D[] = { 
                    "mvjlixape",
                    "jhbxeenpp",
                    "hktthbswy",
                    "rwainuyzh",
                    "ppfxrdzkq",
                    "tpnlqoyjy",
                    "anhapfgbg",
                    "hxmshwyly",
                    "ujfjhrsoa" 
                    };
    // Print 2D array diagonally  for left top to right down
            for(int j = 0; j < array2D.length; j ++){
                for(int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++){
                    if(i+j >= array2D.length)
                        break;
                    System.out.print(array2D[i].charAt(i+j));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for(int j = 1; j < array2D.length; j ++){
                for(int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++){
                    if(i+j >= array2D.length)
                        break;
                    System.out.print(array2D[i + j].charAt(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            // Print diagonally right top to left bottom diagonal
            for(int j = 0; j < array2D.length; j++){
                for(int i = j; i >= 0; i--){
                    System.out.print(array2D[j - i].charAt(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for(int j = 1; j < array2D.length; j ++){
                for(int i = j; i < array2D.length; i++){
                    System.out.print(array2D[array2D.length - i + j - 1].charAt(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: Here I divided printing array diagonally into four parts.